# Make a RichEditBox have scrollbars in C#

Tags: c#, scrollbar, winui-3, richeditbox

I have a WinUI 3 `RichEditBox`, and I need it to have scroll bars. I have to insert it programatically in C#, not XAML. I am putting it in a `Grid` with three rows, which are defined like this:

```xml
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I tried inserting it in a `ScrollViewer`, like this:

```csharp
            Variables.textViews[tabIndex].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            Variables.textViews[tabIndex].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new() {
                Content = Variables.textViews[tabIndex]
            };

            Grid.SetRow(scrollViewer, 2);
            Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 0);
            scrollViewer.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            scrollViewer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            mainPageGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);
```

I notice that when I press and hold enter, the RichEditBox expands not quite fast enough, causing a scroll bar to appear. When I stop, the scroll bar shows, but without a "thumb" (the part to drag to scroll the edit box). See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

---

I tried to set up a tester project, and kept it simple. After some playing around, I discovered that the solution was to put in `Width` and `Height` attributes into the initialization of the `ScrollViewer`. This is what I came up with:

```c-sharp
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new() {
                Content = Variables.textViews[tabIndex],
                Width = 100,
                Height = 100,
                ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled,
                HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled,
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
                VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled,
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
            };
```

This added scroll bars but kept the component's size at 100x100. See image:

[image: Screenshot of result]

I need the `RichEditBox` to fill all the available space. How would I do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you make sure that this is reproducible in a plain WinUI 3 app?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Yes, I can reproduce this. I will update my question with new info.

Comment: Still can't reproduce your issue. Just posted the minimal code that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the minimal code that works. The `ScrollViewer`, which has a `RichEditBox` in it, takes all the available space in the 3rd row.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        RichEditBox richEditBox = new();
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new()
        {
            Content = richEditBox,
        };

        Grid.SetRow(scrollViewer, 2);
        RootGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);
    }
}
```